# 'Symbol not found' error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I wrote my Interface code already, but error. How can I compare two prices of two furniture objects? Am I doing it right in the if statements? The `return` statement says cannot find symbol. How can i fix this?

```
public boolean IsCheaper(Furniture f)
{
    if (f instanceof Furniture)
    {
         boolean status;
         if (price > f.getPrice())
             status = true;
         else if (price < f.getPrice())
             status = false;

    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: interface don't contain any implementation. It just contains method definition.

Comment: `Furniture f` means that `f instanceof Furniture` is *always* true.

Comment: `status` needs to be defined in at least the same code block that it is returned, also, not all paths assign a value to `status`.

Comment: For future reference, please copy and paste the exact error message. You also should keep the error message on its own line to make it more obvious.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not true, `f` could also be null.  But a simple `if (f != null)` would be equivalent and much more clear :-).

Answer (score 1):

```
   public boolean IsCheaper(Furniture f)
    {
      boolean status= false; // or  true
      if (f instanceof Furniture) // if(f!=null) as suggested by a comment
       {

        if (price > f.getPrice())
            status = true;
        else if (price < f.getPrice())
            status = false;

       }
       return status;
     }
```

status should be declared outside if block since you need it outside.

Also is there really a need for if check, instanceof check is needed only if method is accepting a parent class of Furniture

Comment: you should initialize the declaration boolean status= false;

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable `boolean status;` is just the if block `if (f instanceof Furniture)`

and  you have a return statement outside that if block, so as soon as the if block is completed, variable `status` becomes unavailable as it becomes out of scope.

Therefore the compiler is not able to find it and hence says *"cannot find symbol : status "*.

So declare your status variable outside `if (f instanceof Furniture)` block.

Comment: I did that before and it says Variable might not be initialized

Comment: just initaialize it to `true` or `false` when declaring it like `boolean status = false;`

Comment: Are you talking like this @Abu??    public boolean IsCheaper(Furniture f)
 {
    boolean status = true;
    boolean status =false;
  if (f instanceof Furniture)
 {

        if (price > f.getPrice())
             status = true;
        else if (price < f.getPrice())
            status = false;

 }
   return status;

Comment: No just put `boolean status = true;` or `boolean status = false;` any one will do but not both as it will again say compiler error (two variables with same name)